# Disable NonZeroResultCode status details in Rundeck notification on job failure

Tags: rundeck

On job failure (exit code > 0) Rundeck automatically add detailed status informations to the notification attachment:

```
Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1
Execution failed: 3709 in project test_project_1: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [host1: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1 + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(step:1, node:host1)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}, ContextView(node:host1)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}}, base=null)} ]}, Node failures: {host1=[NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status 1 + {dataContext=MultiDataContextImpl(map={ContextView(step:1, node:host1)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}, ContextView(node:host1)=BaseDataContext{{exec={exitCode=0}}}}, base=null)} ]}, status: failed]
```

Can this message by disabled / hiden to only send the script output like in attachment on a success job run?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the "exit 0" in your step wrapping it on some inline script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /root/test 2> /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
  # whatever you want
  echo "Successfully created file"
  exit 0
else
  echo "Could not create file" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```